# Appending DOM events to local file

Tags: javascript, file, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a very complicated site and the easiest way to get what I want from it is simply logging DOM node additions. Over a long period of time. My current code:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationList) {
    for (var mutation of mutationList) {
        for (var child of mutation.addedNodes) {
            appendtofile(path,childasstringorsomething);
        }
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Well, it is not possible to "appendtofile" with javascript. It seems that extensions (at least in firefox/chromium) also are heavily restricted by file size and sandboxed to some worse storage solution choices if any exist at all. My current method is posting to a local port and listening with `ncat -k -l 1234 >> test.txt`, however this is quite suboptimal.

What is the easiest or cleanest way to do this?

Comment: How much size are you talking about? Have you looked at indexedDb? Is storing local sufficient for your app or does it need to be remotely stored?

Comment: It should easily be a couple gb of text / day for a long time. I was hoping to have something like daily text files and archive it properly from there. IndexedDB looks exactly like what I need, however browsers still seem to have size limits, and very ugly/unacceptable enforced auto-delete functionality. I couldn't find anything on making this more stable ex. doing daily backups/cleanups/exports.

Comment: Does it have to be browser based? Familiar with Electron apps? Basically a node server and chrome browser bundled into a desktop app. Due to node server have more file/db access than browser does.

Comment: Extensions can use nativeMessaging to talk to a utility that runs as a native OS process. That utility will obviously be able to write files any way it wants. There are existing nativeMessaging hosts that even run node.js, look for examples.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know any electron but I love the idea. So I tried, loading the site with `view.webContents.loadURL` and attaching the observer with `view.webContents.executeJavaScript`. This works, however once again the observer is stuck in an isolated environment and I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: @charlietfl I forgot to set `{webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}}` for my browserview, it all makes sense at works now, thank you!